# Wifi network hooks and synchronization

Tags: linux, shell, wifi

I have two Linux machines connected by WiFi. One is the AP the other a client. These are buildroot linux, so no systemd but the former SysV environment.

The AP is unreliable and can restart, or even stay down for a while. This is by design and can't be changed.

What I want though is for the client to detect that the AP is up and it is now connected to it and can talk to it.

I have tried several things:

- Use the `ifup`/`ifdown` scripts. However, this is at the HW level and `ifup` scripts will execute when `wlan0` is started. But it is not necessarily connected. Moreover, when the connection is lost with the AP, `ifdown` it not run.
- I tried with a udhcpc hook in `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script.d/`. However it seems the hook is not called when the AP goes down. Indeed, udhcpc is not concerned with the AP status and just retrieve an IP when told to.
- I tried to look at wpa_supplicant hooks but could not find a way to make it run anything on such events.

How to be able to run an arbitrary script on the client machine when a connection is made or lost with the AP ?

Comment: A real question (as in a sentence with a question mark) is appropriate on a Q&A site.

Comment: Have you tried `wpa_cli -a ...` as described in the `README`? This should trigger on CONNECT or DISCONNECT, and wpa_supplicant itself should monitor the available access points (at least in roaming mode, didn't try in normal mode).

Comment: Yes It does work. I didn't read the man page with sufficient attention.